# Redirect in Blazor after POST

Tags: azure-functions, blazor

I have a [Blazor app with an Azure Functions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview). After I've sent a POST I want to redirect the user to a page for the created resource.

I'm not sure which HTTP status code I should return from the API, and how that status code can be handled in Blazor:

**API**:

```cs
[FunctionName("FunctionCreate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "books")]
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var id = 1;

    return new CreatedAtRouteResult(?); // this one?
    return new RedirectToRouteResult(?); // this one?
    return new OkObjectResult(new { id }); // this one?
}
```

How should this be done in Blazor? Should I use `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` and read value from body? Or can the redirect be done automatically?

**Blazor**:

```cs
@code {
    private async Task Create()
    {
        var bookId = await http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/books", new Book());
        
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/books/{bookId}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect programmatically you should inject and use NavigationManager you can use it both in .razor and .cs

also, another way to redirect is using NavLink